# SCSS: Improve performance

Tags: css, extjs, sass, css-selectors

We have project, built in Extjs, and scss. We want to improve performance of scss.
We have used grunt scss-lint, and getting below result

```
NestingDepth: Nesting should be no greater than 3, but was 4
```

How do we reduce nesting till 3 level ? Is there any way which helps us to improve performance of scss ?

Updated. Please look into the below example.

```
.x-grid-row,
  .x-grid-row-alt {
    color: $white-font-color !important;

    &.x-grid-row,
    &.x-grid-row-over {
      color: $white-font-color !important;

      .x-grid-cell {
        color: $white-font-color !important;

        &.clickable-grid-cell {
          color: $white-font-color !important;

          &:hover {
            color: $white-font-color !important;
          }

          .x-grid-cell-inner {
            color: $white-font-color !important;

            div {
              color: $white-font-color !important;
            }

            &:hover {
              color: $white-font-color !important;

              div {
                color: $white-font-color !important;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Show us the code. It's probably just a matter of refactoring

Comment: Are you asking what the error means and how to resolve it or how to improve Sass compilation performance?  Because the 2 aren't related.

Comment: @WesFoster I have updated code into the question.

Comment: @cimmanon I am asking how to improve Sass compilation performance.

Comment: A linter won't help you do that.  Also, I don't know how the error being raised could be any more clear:  you've clearly nested more than 3 times.

Comment: @cimmanon - linter helps me to find out on which line no. error is raised in scss file, and I need to refactor the code at that line no. but I am not sure about it, andI want to reduce nesting level to improve performance in css.

Comment: SO isn't a "refactor my code for me" site (see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295665/are-dry-questions-on-topic).  You don't seem to know what you want other than "less nesting", but it's irrelevant anyway because nesting isn't the bottleneck when it comes to compiling Sass.

Comment: @cimmanon. I understand that more than 3 nesting in scss, can cause performance issue. If that's true I need help in improve the scss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good principle to remember when using the nesting feature in SASS/SCSS: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should. It's best to keep your specificity as low as possible, meaning only nest when you NEED to.

Is there any way you could pull this apart and have the rules on separate lines instead of nesting? Your error would be gone.

In terms of SCSS performance, don't worry about it. That's the point of it being a pre-processor: it does the hard work before hitting the browser. You SHOULD start worrying, though, if you use bad practice and end up bloating your CSS for the user in the browser. But I don't really see that being a concern here.